# How to check if a xpath/element exists in XML?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

How to check, if a tag/xpath/element exists or not ?

**Sample.xml**

```
<layer>
    <value>Random</value>
    <value>12345</value>
</layer>
<layer>
    <value>Last_Name</value>
    <value>ABCD</value>
</layer>
<layer>
    <value>dynamic</value>
    <value>a1234bcd</value>
 </layer>
```

**Sample.py**

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('sample.xml')
print tree.xpath('//layer[value="Last_Name"]/value')[1].text
```

Here, I'm trying to find the value of the  tag **'Last_Name'** i.e., **ABCD**
How to check if an element 'Last_Name' exists or not ?
Because, an exception is caught as **"list index out of range"**.
Is it possible to check if an element exists ?

Answer (score 1):

Match by text; then get the content of the following sibling:

```
tree.xpath('//layer/value[text()="Last_Name"]/following-sibling::value/text()')
```